# socket.emit not emitting messages to the sender

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

1. **'socket.emit**' not sending messages to the client which sent it,while
2. **'socket.broadcast.emit'** sending messages to all the clients including the sender.

I cannot figure out what I am missing here. 
For the second case, I checked for socket.id while sending the message and logged it when response is received,it turned out to be the same

socket.js

```
var socket = require('socket.io')(),
socketApi = {};

socketApi.io = socket;

socketApi.io.on('connection',(client) => {
    client.on('clientMessage', (msg) => {
        console.log('hi');
        client.emit('serverMessage',msg);
    })
    client.on('disconnect',() => {
        socketApi.io.emit('serverMessage','client is disconnected');
        console.log('disconnected');
    })
})


module.exports = socketApi;
```

client.js

```
getServerResponse() {
        socket.on('serverMessage',(msg) => {
                console.log(msg);
            })
    }
```

Comment: in `client.js` - do you call the `getServerResponse' function?

Comment: yep...I am getting a response when I use SocketAPI.io.emit or client.broadcast.emit

Comment: `client.on('clientMessage', (msg) => {;` what is the semicolon doing here?

Comment: updated the code..was just a typo while posting question, problem stil remains

Comment: would you do `console.log(client);` instead of  `console.log('hi');`?

Comment: or rather `console.log(client.constructor.name);`

Comment: I tried it, I checked socket.id while sending, logged it on server as mentioned by you both turns out to be the same

Comment: In case of client.constructor.name it logs 'Socket' which is okay according to me

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs `broadcast.emit` sends to all except the sender and `emit` sends to the sender only: https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/.

I was in the same issue so I ended up calling both:

```
// socket.io server
io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('message', (data) => {
    messages.push(data)
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', data) // sends to all except the sender
    socket.emit('message', data)  // sends to the sender
  })
})
```